# Polynomial division question with trig and bynomial

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I have the polynomial $f=(\cos a+x\sin a)^n$ and the polynomial $g=x^2+1$ and I have to find the remainder of the divison: $\frac fg$.

I tried something using the euclidean division but couldn't work it out..

Comment: $f(x)=\left(x^2+1\right)q(x)+(b x + c)$ implies $x f(x)=\left(x^2+1\right)(x q(x)+b)+ (c x -b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $g(x)$ has degree $2$, the degree of the remainder is $1$, at most. That is, the remainder is $bx+c$, for some $b,c\in\mathbb C$.

Let $q(x)$ be the quotient. Then $f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)+bx+c$ and therefore$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}f(i)=bi+c\\f(-i)=-bi+c.\end{array}\right.$$But $f(i)=e^{ian}$ and $f(-i)=e^{-ian}$. So$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}bi+c=e^{ian}\\-bi+c=e^{-ian}.\end{array}\right.$$Therefore, $b=\sin(na)$ and $c=\cos(na)$.

Comment: I can't use the Euler's formula because I'm only in 12th grade and didn't learn it yet... even tho I know about it and it's existence.. can you help me with another way of thinking about it?